# create fb user using fb api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a facebook app and for that  I need to create a fake fb user for each user that signs up into my app.

Is there an api available for creating facebook users?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Signing up users cannot be done in Facebook Graph API and creating fake FB users is one of the abuse use of API. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purpose you can create test user with API. The document is provided [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/accounts/test-users#publish). By specifying installed=true parameter, your app is authorized by default. It's just easy as below:

```
curl -X POST \
     -d "installed=true" \
        https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id}/accounts/test-users
```